# Is there an Eclipse command that lists classes that implement an Interface X?

Tags: eclipse

A shortcut that does that will be helpful. I am both new to Eclipse and navigating a large code base, which makes going back and forth between implementations and interfaces a little bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that by selecting the `interface` and hitting `F4` (Open Type Hierarchy) or just Right-click on the interface(or even class) name and select Open Type Hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: Or `Ctrl-T` for a quick popup window.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl T on a class name: quick type hierarchy

F4 on a class name: type hierarchy

On a method name: Ctrl hover: a menu appears with "Open implementation".

Answer (score 1):

Choose the Interface and push F4(Open Type Hierarchy) or open interface double click on Iface name and push Ctrl+T(Quick Type Hierarchy)